# Stick image title under image with align="right"

Tags: html, css, image

I don't know how to formulate this well, but my problem is that i have an image thats wrapped around with text, and i need a title under that image. I will try to explain with a picture

[image]

The image has this code ;

```
<img src="../assets/img/fotos/nieuws/nieuwsbericht3.jpg" align="right" width="280px" height="150px">
```

How can i get the

```
<div align="right" style="font-size: 8px">Schetsimpressie La Dolce Villa III, start verkoop 2de kwartaal 2014</div>
```

get underneath it?

this is the whole code of it;

```
 <img src="../assets/img/fotos/nieuws/nieuwsbericht3.jpg" align="right" width="280px" height="150px">
            <div align="right" style="font-size: 8px">Schetsimpressie La Dolce Villa III, start verkoop 2de kwartaal 2014</div>
            Bovendien start in het tweede kwartaal van 2014 ook nog eens de verkoop van zes halfvrijstaande en twee vrijstaande woningen in La Dolce Villa III, de laatste fase in deze groene leef- en woonomgeving aan de rand van Gemert. 
            Alle woningen worden gerealiseerd op basis van Persoonlijke Huisvesting, dus met volledige vrijheid voor de kopers als het gaat om afwerking, indeling en extra's van de woning. 
            Je stelt daarmee kopers in staat om zelf hun woning voor het overgrote deel vorm te geven."
```

and it looks likes this now 
[image]

I'm sorry if its very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Align` is deprecated on `div` and you should really use CSS to achieve this.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/t2U7h/1/)**

Try this CSS:

```
.right-image {
    float: right;
}
.caption {
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

Then this HTML:

```
<div class="right-image">
    <img src="../assets/img/fotos/nieuws/nieuwsbericht3.jpg" width="280px" height="150px">
    <div class="caption">Schetsimpressie La Dolce Villa III, start verkoop 2de kwartaal 2014</div>
</div>
<div>
    Bovendien start in het tweede kwartaal van 2014 ook nog eens de verkoop van zes halfvrijstaande en twee vrijstaande woningen in La Dolce Villa III, de laatste fase in deze groene leef- en woonomgeving aan de rand van Gemert. 
    Alle woningen worden gerealiseerd op basis van Persoonlijke Huisvesting, dus met volledige vrijheid voor de kopers als het gaat om afwerking, indeling en extra's van de woning. 
    Je stelt daarmee kopers in staat om zelf hun woning voor het overgrote deel vorm te geven.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [several ways](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html) to achieve this, ranging from pure-HTML

```
<table align=right>
<caption align=bottom>caption text</caption>
<tr><td><img ...>
</table>
```

to modernist HTML5 + CSS

```
<style>
figure { margin: 0: float: right }
</style>
...
<figure>
  <img ...>
  <figcaption>caption text</figcaption>
</figure>
```